# Почему VSC не видит модуль telebot?

Tags: python, telebot

Установил библиотеку `pyTelegramBotAPI` через `cmd`. Все прошло успешно, но когда начал писать код, то `VSC` не видит модуля:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\питончик\my_bot.py", line 1, in <module>
import telebot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'
```

Пробовал удалять и заново устанавливать, но не помогло.

Comment: Не VSC не видит модуль, а интерпретатор питона. Похоже, у вас несколько интерпретатор стоит. В один поставили бота. А другой вызывает VSC

Comment: А как убрать интерпретатор которые мешает?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter или https://python.plainenglish.io/how-to-set-default-python-interpreter-in-vs-code-76c38c210dc3

Comment: @gil9red Я думаю что несколько окружений, т.к. обычно люди путаю интерпретатор и окружение)

Comment: @tonysdev, а какая разница? :) Открыл папку окружения "\venv\Scripts" и вижу там "python.exe" :)

Comment: @gil9red Ну тут уже чисто вкусовщина, считаю что интерпретатор это сам python, а окружение это уже настроенная среда для разработки определенных модулей(бэк, фронт), по крайней мере так все кондисты говорят)

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая же проблема. Попробуйте добавить папку библиотеки в проект. В крайнем случае установите Pycharm и откройте проект в нём.